# Login based on user groups Symfony 1.4.20 and sfDoctrineGuard

Tags: authentication, symfony1, symfony-1.4, sfguard

I'm developing a Symfony1 app and I'm using sfDoctrineGuard plugin, all is configured and working fine! But I've a problem, I created 3 users:

```
username              group_name
administrador         super_administrator
user1                 group1
user2                 -
```

I've also two apps site and admin. User administrator can login and access every content at admin side others like user1 and user2 can't. user1 and every users belongs to group1 can login at site frontend, user2 and users without group1 assigned can't. I tried securing the module dashboard which is the entry point for site app in this way:

```
default:
   is_secure: true
   credentials: group1
```

But it's not working I get always this message:

> Oops! The page you asked for is secure and you do not have proper credentials.

How can I do this? What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sfDoctrineGuard` converts `permissions` to credentials so you should create permissions like group1 (or something more meaningful) and assing them to users or groups. `sfDoctrineGuard` will aggregate group and user permissions. This way you can use a permission name everywhere you need a credential. If you would like to disallow login for specific permissions you should override `sfGuardValidatorUser` or `sfGuardSecurityUser::signIn` and use `$user->hasPermission('group1')` to check for a user has a required permission.

Comment: Hi @1ed, I've tried creating a permission called "acceso_publico" and then in apps/site/config/security.yml write this code `default:
  is_secure: true credentials: [acceso_publico]` of course I assigned those permissions to a group and also to a user (just in case) but don't works, get the same message > Oops! The page you asked for is secure and you do not have proper credentials.> http://rayundown.devserver/css/main.css > Login below to gain access what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @ReynierPM credentials are cached in session so you have to log out and/or delete the session cookie to changes take effect. Please check if `myUser` class extends `sfGuardSecurityUser`.

Comment: thanks now it works. One more question I create two users, asigned the first one to "group1" and the second one to none group, I secure the application "site" and set credentials to "group1" can the second user login into site?

Comment: yes, he can log in but he will be asked to log in again with another account because he don't have the required credential. This is what the "Oops! The page you asked for is secure and you do not have proper..." page is about. If you would like to deny logging in you have to modify e.g. the validator as I wrote. (Feel free to ask for help in an another question if you need.)

Comment: so this is why I get the login form once and once when try to login with the user that haven't credentials and for that reason I tough is I can't login with any other user, I'm right? How I must ask for this change to the validator? I don't get the question in my mind